# How to Disassemble my microwave door?

Tags: repair, cleaning, microwave-oven

We had an incident where boiling milk boiled over and spilt all over the counter and dripped onto the microwave where it seems to have entered a space in my microwave door. I would like to open it. However disassembling the screws only got me so far as below. I need to know how to separate the glass panes  now. It does seem similar to the trim around most microwave doors but seems subtly different. If I try to insert a screw driver in and try to lever up the plastic band surrounding the glass, there is some amount of "give" but nothing pops, also it appears to be stressing on the think rubber seal between the glass and the plastic, as soon as I saw this I stopped.

The milk is ultimately inbetween the two panes of glass, so I was wondering if it is possible to disassemble it further. It is a wall mounted microwave cum Convection oven by Aristan.[image]

Comment: Depending on where the metal grille is (between the panes?) you could seriously damage it even with extreme care. This would allow microwaves to easily exit the oven. Be very careful - burns aren’t fun.

Comment: Look for directions on replacing the glass. I have done that on my Kitchenaid oven doors with help from YouTube videos. If you can find similar information for your oven then follow those directions and just clean without actually replacing the glass.

Comment: @manassehkatz I have tried my level best, Have not been able to find any..

Answer (score 1):

Try using 2 putty knives, about 1 inch wide. Choose the flexible style that have nice thin ends. Start on one of the short sides close to a corner, with the 2 knife ends side-by-side. Alternate the 2 knives like a step exerciser, prying to lift the plate away from the sticky strip. Work both sides of the corner, but mostly along the short side toward the other corner. Increase the height until you can lift it slowly like a book cover.
Re-assemble with 2-sided tape of high-temp RTV caulking.